# Display PHP within HTML values

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

What is the correct way to display a value in a link using php?

The (Advanced Custom Fields) php works correctly outside of the html.

```
Book on Expedia.com <a class="alignright" href="<?php the_field( 'expedia' ); ?>" target="_blank" ><input class="resume_contact_button" type="button" value="<?php the_field( 'low_rate' ); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: just write `echo` after `php` tab like `<?php echo the_field('...'); ?>`

Comment: @ksr89 No need, `the_...` functions in ACF output the field already.

Comment: Have tried a few alternative, no luck yet `<?php echo field( 'low_rate' ); ?>`

Comment: am not able to understand your question.  what do you mean by it works correctly outside of the html?

Comment: you might not be able to see anything, because the field is empty.

Comment: try doing var_dump(the_field('expedia'))

Comment: Thanks @MortalViews yes the field was empty. This is what worked in the end. `<?php echo the_field( 'low_rate' ); ?>`

Comment: you don't need to use 'echo' with the_field.

Comment: the value will be displayed if it's NOT empty, otherwise you won't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the function returns a printed value:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Link</a>
```

If not (using the echo statement):

```
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>">Link</a>
```

You can also use `print()` as part of a more complex expression where echo cannot.

By the contrary, when you want to use HTML into PHP, I recommend to close PHP and open it again after the HTML code, instead of using `echo "<a href='#'></a>";` like this example:

```
<?php my_function() { ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Link</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Your PHP code is ok, but probably the function returns an empty value. Also, close the INPUT tag with `/>`.